# Jmeter Performance test using dynamic user_id per minute

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

Can someone help me simulate this scenario.

-Example I have a list of 10,000 user_id,

-Every minute I want to use fix 600 user_id on the list.

-Next minute will select different set of 600 user_id

-Duration 30 minutes

I tried to use loop controller unfortunately it shows only 600 request on AWS Cloud metric if I use cache manager. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to limit the load to 600 requests per minute or to 10 requests per second.

There are following options:

1. Built in:

   - [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
   - [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
2. Available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)):

   - [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)

Comment: actually I'm able to do part but changing the user_id per minute I'm having problem to simulate it.

Example 1st minute list of 600 user_id
2nd minute different set of 600 user_id